# Generic Makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I am looking for a generic makefile, which will will build all C++ files in the current directory and all sub-directories (e.g, source, test files, gtest, etc)

I have spent a few hours trying out several and finally settled on the solution from [make file with source subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273374/make-file-with-source-subdirectories).

I need to make three changes to it:

1. Gtest uses *.cc for its C++ files and I have others which use *.cpp
2. I need to be able to define multiple search paths.
3. Add compiler flags, like -W all

I have managed to break the makefile, shown below, such that running make gives me

> make: *** No rule to make target `%.cpp=%.o', needed by`myProgram'. 
>   Stop.

How can I make it do those three things?

```
# Recursively get all *.cpp in this directory and any sub-directories
SRC = $(shell find . -name *.cc) $(shell find . -name *.cpp)

INCLUDE_PATHS = -I ../../../ -I gtest -I dummies

#This tells Make that somewhere below, you are going to convert all your source into 
#objects
# OBJ =  src/main.o src/folder1/func1.o src/folder1/func2.o src/folder2/func3.o

OBJ = $(SRC:%.cc=%.o %.cpp=%.o)

#Tells make your binary is called artifact_name_here and it should be in bin/
BIN = myProgram

# all is the target (you would run make all from the command line). 'all' is dependent
# on $(BIN)
all: $(BIN)

#$(BIN) is dependent on objects
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    g++ 

#each object file is dependent on its source file, and whenever make needs to create
# an object file, to follow this rule:
%.o: %.cc
    g++ -c $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $< -o $@
```

---

[Update] Thanks for the help so far. To address a few of the comments, I have no control over the mixed *.cc and *.cpp fiel extensions, and I can say that there won't ever be a source file in the directory tree which I do not wish to include in the build.

I am still having trouble with the SRC, as no input files are found. I guess that I should look more into the find command as it has been a while since I used Linux.

Comment: Variable expansion can only have *one* pattern replacement. Not two. So your `OBJ = $(SRC:%.cc=%.o %.cpp=%.o)` is your problem there. Add a second line with the second replacement if you want to do both. Also only running find once instead of twice is more efficient.

Comment: You're trying to build all `.o` files as if they all came from a `.cc` - but that's not the case. Some came from `.cpp` files. Easiest would be to just use a single extension everywhere. Is that not possible?

Comment: Think about what you are doing.  If I want to keep a file in the directory, but not include it in the project, how will you handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a rather poor makefile: it does not build header dependencies for you, so you are likely to end up with corrupted builds.

I shamelessly recommend [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7321954/412080).

Answer (score 1):

Etan points out your problem.  But you don't have to perform two replacements, just:

```
OBJ := $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SRCS)))
```

And, you should always be using `:=`, not `=`, for assignment when using the `shell` function.